# ContextMenu ItemsSource binding problem

Tags: wpf, binding, mvvm, contextmenu, itemssource

There is a problem with ContextMenu with wpf usercontrol. I wrote a usercontrol, and this usercontrol have a windowsformhost, and i want to handle the right button contextmenu of the windows control with wpf context menu.

So i send a message to wpf user control to call contextMenu.IsOpen = true, and i fill the contextMenu.ItemsSourceProperty a binding. But when i call the contextmenu.IsOpen = true, The contextMenu.Items.Count == 0, how can i solve this problem?

Here is my code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ControlEase.Inspec.Drawing.CanvasEditorView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ControlEase.Inspec.Drawing"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}"/>
    </Style>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="graphicsMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding Commands}"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu ContextMenu="{StaticResource graphicsMenu}"/>
</UserControl.ContextMenu>
<Grid>
    <local:InitializedUserControl local:LoaderHelper.InitializedCommand="{Binding OpenCommand}" >
        <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="windowsHost"  local:CanvasContainerExtensions.Canvas="{Binding Model}"/>
        <EventCommander.Mappings>
            <CommandEvent Event="GotFocus" Command="{Binding ActiveCommand}"/>
            <CommandEvent Event="LostFocus" Command="{Binding DeActiveCommand}"/>
        </EventCommander.Mappings>
    </local:InitializedUserControl>
</Grid>
```

And when i get the message in the xaml.cs, i called ContextMenu.IsOpen = true. The ContextMenu != null, but ContextMenu.Itmes.Count == 0, and there is no binding error in the output pad. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Here, you're setting the `ContextMenu` property of the `ContextMenu`:

```
<ContextMenu ContextMenu="{StaticResource graphicsMenu}"/>
```

As a result, you'll have an empty outer `ContextMenu`, with a `ContextMenu` of its own that contains the items you need. The outer context menu won't ever display because it has nothing in it, but if it did and it rendered large enough, you could right-click it to see the inner context menu, which is where your menu items would be hiding away.

The `ContextMenu` resource is redundant. You could just have this:

```
<UserControl.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Commands}"/>
</UserControl.ContextMenu>
```